# Count on Groupby & update column value C# DataTable

Tags: c#, group-by, datatable, count, rows

I have a Datatable like this:

| Id | Amount1 | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 30 | 30 |
| 8 | 22 | 12 |
| 7 | 11 | 31 |
| 8 | 15 | 51 |

I need to get my datatable like this:

| Id | Amount1 | total | IdCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 30 | 30 | 1 |
| 8 | 22 | 12 | 2 |
| 7 | 11 | 31 | 1 |
| 8 | 15 | 51 | 2 |

How Can I count the same ids and update in rows i.e if id 8 is repeating two times it should add 2 in both rows

Comment: please take a look at how to use code formatting. it is mentioned on the same page that you used to create your Question ... and would make your sample data MUCH easier to read. [*grin*] ///// also, where is your code? how did it fail to do what you wanted done?

Comment: how does your current code look like and what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a lookup to count the ids:

```
// copy structure and data into new DataTable
DataTable tblCount = yourOriginalDataTable.Copy();
// add the count column
tblCount.Columns.Add("IdCount", typeof(int)); 
// create a dictionary like collection where the key is the id
var idCounter = tblCount.AsEnumerable().ToLookup(row => row.Field<int>("Id"));
// loop the rows and update the column with the correct count value
foreach(DataRow row in tblCount.Rows)
    row.SetField("IdCount", idCounter[row.Field<int>("Id")].Count());
```